# Gen for a custom data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, generator, truthtable

I was trying to make a truth table for a list of strings. 
Say, I have a list `["a","b"]` and as an output, I want 
`[[("a",True),("b",True)],
[("a",True),("b",False)],
[("a",False),("b",True)],
[("a",False),("b",False)]]`

Each of those instances in the truth table are a custom data type defined as

```
data TableRow = [(String,Bool)]
```

Is there any easier way of doing this? Until now I have been doing this

---

```
genRow :: [String] -> [TableRow]
genRow [] = []
genRow (x:xs) = ((makeRow x True) : genRow xs) ++ 
            ((makeRow x False) : genRow xs)
```

Quite obviously, this does not quite give me what I expect. Note that `makeRow` just takes in a `String` and a `Bool` and returns a `TableRow`.

Is there any cleaner way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: What does `makeRow` do?

Comment: Are you saying that you want the cartesian product two lists? Do you know list comprehensions?

Comment: `data TableRow = [(String,Bool)]` is not valid. You need a data constructor name.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your program is that `genRow :: [String] -> [TableRow]` generates **a list of `TableRow`** elements, and you cannot use the cons `(:)` constructor on a `(String,Bool)` and `TableRow` since `TableRow` is `[[(String,Bool)]]`.

You can however easily use *list comprehension* for that:

```
genRow :: [String] -> [[(String,Bool)]]
genRow [] = [[]]
genRow (x:xs) = [(x,b):ti | b <- [True,False], ti <- ts]
    where ts = genRow xs
```

The first statement should thus generate a list **with one element**: the **empty list `[]`** (not the empty list as result). Furthermore we use list comprehension: we iterate over the two `Bool`s `True` and `False` for `b` and for each such value, we iterate over the possible values as tails `ts` and prepend the `(x,b)` to each of the possible tails.

This gives:

```
*Main> genRow ["A","B","C"]
[[("A",True),("B",True),("C",True)],
 [("A",True),("B",True),("C",False)],
 [("A",True),("B",False),("C",True)],
 [("A",True),("B",False),("C",False)],
 [("A",False),("B",True),("C",True)],
 [("A",False),("B",True),("C",False)],
 [("A",False),("B",False),("C",True)],
 [("A",False),("B",False),("C",False)]]
*Main> genRow ["Foo","Bar"]
[[("Foo",True),("Bar",True)],
 [("Foo",True),("Bar",False)],
 [("Foo",False),("Bar",True)],
 [("Foo",False),("Bar",False)]]
```

(new lines added for readability)

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much. I was not quite aware of list comprehensions, and did not know of this particular syntax. Just to clarify, 
`genRow (x:xs) = [(x,b):ti | b <- [True,False], ti <- ts]
    where ts = genRow xs`
Does this work because it makes a separate list for True and False in each case?

Comment: What do you mean with a *separate list*?